# How to remove comma just from incorrectly typed address?

Tags: python, regex, string

If I am given a list of addresses and it only contains one incorrect address such as,

444, street name, secondary adr, city, state and zip

How can I just remove the comma after the number without removing all other commas in python?

I need the other commas so I can split the string by commas and mapped into the corresponding fields.

Comment: `str.split(',', 1)` ?

Comment: str.replace(',', '', 1) ... replace only the first occurrence with the empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code using `re`

```
import re

data = '444, street name, secondary adr, city, state and zip'
print(data)
print(re.sub(r'^(\d+),', r'\1', data))
```

Output

```
444, street name, secondary adr, city, state and zip
444 street name, secondary adr, city, state and zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
data = '444, street name, secondary adr, city, state and zip'
print(data)
print(" ".join(data.split(',', 1)))
```

Output

```
444, street name, secondary adr, city, state and zip
444  street name, secondary adr, city, state and zip
```

Comment: This replace the first occurrence only. What if I have, '444  street name, secondary adr, city, state and zip'. It will replace the first occurrence, which I don't want it to replace.

Comment: Then you need `re` regular expression

Comment: What I mean is, I have a list of correct addresses. But only one of those incorrect, such as '444,  street name, secondary adr, city, state and zip'. I only want to remove the comma from this one, but ignore the rest of addresses. I was thinking of using re and just find any comma after a number and remove it.